# Is there a way to work with Python (e.g.: TensorFlow or Sci-kit learn libs) in Flutter apps?

Tags: python, firebase, tensorflow, scikit-learn, flutter

I am creating an app for school and I could use some Machine Learning in it. Although, the libraries I know that I could use to process and predict my data are all for Python.

Is there a way that I could get data from Flutter app, process it in a Python backend and return the output to the Flutter app?

Or is there an alternative I could use on Flutter? I already plan to use Firebase in the app, is there any kind of machine learning tool for data stored on Firebase?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you wanting to do the processing with Python on the device or on a server?

Comment: What I was planning to do was do the process directly on the device, connecting it just with Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your python (scikit-learn) code neither in iOS nor in Android.

However, the Tensorflow is available for [mobile](https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/).

Currently, you cannot use Tensorlfow directly in your Flutter application (with Dart), but you can use it in the native part of your mobile app and link it to your Flutter application using [platform-channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: To your knowledge is this still the case now?

Comment: There is this new plugin that helps accessing Tensorflow Lite APIs in Flutter.
https://pub.dev/packages/tflite
I haven't used it myself but looks promissing.

Answer (score 1):

Flutter builds the apps. The apps can communicate with any backend of your choice - or with multiple backends if you need it. For example, it can connect to Firebase for user data, etc., and connect to a different backend for machine learning (e.g. Google Cloud AI).

Comment: I don't know Google Cloud AI yet, can I run tensorflow and scikit-learn codes on it?

Comment: If you need TensorFlow, you can run it anywhere you like, e.g. Google Cloud Platform, AWS, or on your own server. And make your Flutter app talk to it like it would talk to any other server.

Answer (score 1):

Rather you can use python plus tensowflow in your jupyter notebook and train your model and then upload your custom model on the firebase ml kit and from their you can use it.

The ml kit in the firebase is very handy in applying machine learning.

Answer (score 1):

Yes It's possible and quite easy to use scikit learn and other python packages such as numpy, scipy, pandas, etc using [chaquopy](https://pub.dev/packages/chaquopy) plugin for flutter.